# Use external files in config.json using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am developing a mobile app using cordova and dojo. I want to modify the config.json so that I can have my views come from an external site. I have all the required fields filled in my config.json.

Here's a sample part of my config that I want to modify:

```
"views":{
    "page1":{
        "controller":"filePathToJs",
        "template":"filepathToHtml.html"
    }
}
```

What I want to modify is the controller and the template to use an external file like "https://foo.js" and "https//foo.html" respectively. I've tried just setting the paths to the site I want, but dojo won't load those pages.

If anybody can be of some help here that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

hm I've never used dojo mobile, but by quickly looking at the [documentation for configuration file](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/app.html#the-configuration-file) you can set the package paths. So that means that something like the following should work:

```
"loaderConfig" : {
  "paths": {
    "mypackage" : "//some/sample/external/url"
   }
}
```

and then in your controller settings:

```
"views":{
    "page1":{
        "controller":"myPackage/filePathToJs",
        "template":"myPackage/filepathToHtml.html"
    }
}
```

Give it a try I reckon that should work.